# Trying to check if a Mysql user exists in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to check if a MYSQL user exists. This is as far as I have got. I fall down on capturing the answer from the output.

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo -e "What is the MYSQL username called"
    read DBUSER
    if [ -z "$DBUSER" ]
    then
    exit

    mysql -uUSER -pPASS -e "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DBUSER')";

    if 
    yes
    do this
    else
    do this
```

this is the output I am getting

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'bob') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Can any one help please

Answer (score 10):

Thanks very much for your help. Here is the final result working.

It needs the -sse

```
RESULT_VARIABLE="$(mysql -uUSER -pPASS -sse "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DBUSER')")"

if [ "$RESULT_VARIABLE" = 1 ]; then
echo "TRUE"
else
  echo "FALSE"
fi
```

Comment: rather obvious, but just to be affirmative... this worked for me with `shell_exec`  --> `$is_mysql_user = shell_exec('mysql --defaults-extra-file=MYPATHTOSTOREDCREDENTIALS -sse "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = \'' . $user_name . '\')"');`

Answer (score 3):

Assigning the result to a variable can be done like this:

```
RESULT_VARIABLE="$(mysql -uUSER -pPASS -se "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DBUSER')")"
```

And you can also alias a column in MySQL, btw.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DBUSER') AS does_it_exist
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am then trying to pick up the result. This gives me an error

if [ $RESULT_VARIABLE = "1" ]; then
echo "true"
else
  echo "try again"
fi